# update tkinter label with mouse click

Tags: python, tkinter

I am the beginner in Python and am trying to code a tictactoe game with `tkinter`. My class named `Cell` extends `Tkinter.Label`. The `Cell` class contains data fields `emptyLabel`, `xLabel` and `oLabel`. This is my code so far for class `Cell`:

```
from tkinter import *

class Cell(Label):
    def __init__(self,container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.emptyImage=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Python34\\image\\empty.gif")
        self.x=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Python34\\image\\x.gif")
        self.o=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Python34\\image\\o.gif")

    def getEmptyLabel(self):
        return self.emptyImage

    def getXLabel(self):
        return self.x

    def getOLabel(self):
        return self.o
```

and my main class is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from Cell import Cell

class MainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Tac Tic Toe")

        self.frame1=Frame(window)
        self.frame1.pack()

        for i in range (3):
            for j in range (3):
                self.cell=Cell(self.frame1)
                self.cell.config(image=self.cell.getEmptyLabel())

                self.cell.grid(row=i,column=j)

        self.cell.bind("<Button-1>",self.flip)

        frame2=Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        self.lblStatus=Label(frame2,text="Game Status").pack()

        window.mainloop()

   def flip(self,event):
       self.cell.config(image=self.cell.getXLabel())

MainGUI()
```

The code displays an empty cell image on cell 3x3, but when I click the cell to update the empty cell image to X image. It currently only happens on the empty label in row 3 column 3.

My question is: How to change the label on a mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep reassigning `self.cell`, and then when that part is done you bind a mouse button to the last cell. Bind the mouse button to each cell within the loop.

The callback function is also hard-coded to only look at `self.cell`, which you kept reassigning to end up with only the last one. In addition to binding the mouse button to each cell, you'll have to change the callback function to look at the proper cell.

In `__init__`:

```
for i in range (3):
    for j in range (3):
        cell=Cell(self.frame1)
        cell.config(image=self.cell.getEmptyLabel())

        cell.grid(row=i,column=j)

        cell.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, cell=cell: self.flip(cell))
```

Or, without using `lambda`:

```
for i in range (3):
    for j in range (3):
        cell=Cell(self.frame1)
        cell.config(image=self.cell.getEmptyLabel())

        cell.grid(row=i,column=j)

        def temp(event, cell=cell):
            self.flip(cell)

        cell.bind("<Button-1>", temp)
```

In `flip`:

```
def flip(self, cell):
    self.cell.config(image=cell.getXLabel())
```

Comment: thanks you for code and it works but can you explain or maybe give some clue so i can googling what cell.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, cell=cell: self.flip(cell)), i understand button-1 but rest code i dont, thanks anyway

Comment: how if i avoid to use lambda? there is a way??,, thanks

Comment: @ebil - `lambda` defines an inline, anonymous function. This one takes an `event` (the mouse click) and a `cell` with a default argument of the current cell. This default argument is necessary in this case - without it, `cell` will be looked up only when you click, at which point it will always be the cell in row 3, column 3.

Comment: thanks mate for the clue,, but it is possible if i dont use lambda??

Comment: @ebil - Sure; just use a regular function definition. See the edit.